# update sql table current row

Tags: mysql, max, row

Complete noob alert!  I need to store a largish set of data fields (480) for each of many devices i am measuring.  Each field is a Decimal(8,5). First, is this an unreasonably large table?  I have no experience really, so if it is unmanageable, I might start thinking of an alternative storage method.

Right now, I am creating a new row using INSERT, then trying to put the 480 data values in to the new row using UPDATE (in a loop).  Currently each UPDATE is overwriting the entire column. How do I specify only to modify the last row?  For example, with a table ("magnitude") having columns "id", "field1", "field2",...:

sql UPDATE magnitude SET field1 = 3.14;  this modifies the entire "field1" column.

Was trying to do something like:
sql UPDATE magnitude SET field1 = 3.14 WHERE id = MAX(id)

Obviously I am a complete noob.  Just trying to get this one thing working and move on...  Did look around a lot but can't find a solution.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inserting a row and then updating it with values, you should insert an entire row, with populated values, at once, using the `insert` command.

I.e.

```
insert into tTable (column1, column2, ..., column n) values (datum1, datum2, ..., datum n)
```

Your table's definition should have the ID column with property `identity`, which means that it will autofill it for you when you insert, i.e. you don't need to specify it.

Re: appropriateness of the schema, I think 480 is a large number of columns. However, this is a straightforward enough example that you could try it and determine empirically if your system is able to give you the performance you need.

If I were doing this myself, I would go for a different solution that has many rows instead of many columns:

Create a table `tDevice (ID int, Name nvarchar)`

Create a table `tData (ID int, Device_ID int, Value decimal(8,5))`

-- With a foreign key on `Device_ID` back to `tDevice.ID`

Then, to populate:

Insert all your devices in `tDevice`

Insert one row into `tData` for every Device / Data combination
-- i.e. 480 x n rows, n being the number of devices

Then, you can query the data you want like so:

`select * from tData join tDevice on tDevice.ID = tData.Device_ID`

Comment: I am working on the single statement solution now.  only issue is that it will be long. I'm working in Max/msp so not sure if there are any limitations in constructing such a long symbol.  Being a sql noob, not sure I understand your alternate suggestion, but will cogitate on it, thanks.

Comment: No problem. The alternate suggestion would have very short insert statements: _for each (device) { for each (datum) {_ `insert into tData (Device_ID, Datum) values (<current device ID>, <current datum>)` _} }_.

Comment: One note - if on SO you find your question has been answered, please mark it answered by clicking on the check mark next to it. Cheers!